# How to handle line break and comma using PySpark

Tags: apache-spark

Here is the thing: I am trying to read a csv file using spark, but I have 2 problems: cells with line break and cells with commas inside text.

So I have:

| column A | column B |
| --- | --- |
| This is a normal record | 1 |
| This is a record with, a comma in here | 2 |
| Here I have a \n escape char , maybe a comma | 3 |

Basically I already tried every options I found on internet, but it's not working:

```
df = (spark.read
      .option("header", "true")
      .option("inferSchema","true")
      .option("multiLine","true")
      .option("quoteMode","ALL")
      .option("ignoreLeadingWhiteSpace","true")
      .option("ignoreTrailingWhiteSpace","true")
      .option("escape","\n")
      .option("escape", "\"")
      .option("escapeQuote", "true")
      .option("quote", "\"")
      .option("wholeFile","true")
      .csv('my_csv_file',  header = True, quote='"',escape='\\',multiLine='true', sep = ",",  unescapedQuoteHandling = "BACK_TO_DELIMITER"))
```

Please help me!! :(

Comment: can you please cat you file data & attache screen shot ?

Comment: Dont know how to attach a file in here, and stackoverflow doesn't allows me to insert an image. But it's exactly the table I described above: sometimes with a comma, sometimes with a line break.